# Check only one checkbox at a time (checkbox given inside a delegate)

Tags: qt, checkbox, qml, delegates

Currently all checkboxes are checkable . I need to check only one checkbox.

```js
    TableView {
       id: table 
       anchors.fill: parent 

       model:  display_model 
       TableViewColumn {
          role: "checkbox"
          delegate: CheckBox {
              id: delegate_chekbox
                onCheckedChanged: {
                    console.log(model.index)
                }
          }
       }
```

Comment: Ok, but what is the question? What did you try to do and what didn't work out. Please clarify.

Comment: Perhaps RadioButton instead of CheckBox?

Answer (score 1):

I want to add that the desired behavior can also be achieved with checkboxes.
CheckBox inherits AbstractButton and therefor can be added to a ButtonGroup. If the ButtonGroup has "exclusive" set to true (default) only one button can be checked at a time. This also offers you easy access to the current checked button etc. via the ButtonGroup component.

```
TableView {
    id: table
    anchors.fill: parent

    model:  10

    delegate: CheckBox {
        ButtonGroup.group: group
    }
}

ButtonGroup {
    id: group
    exclusive: true //its default "true" so you don't really have to set this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For completness: As mentioned in the comments from @StephenQuan, if you just need one selected item, use RadioButtons. Here a small example:

```
TableView {
    id: table
    anchors.fill: parent

    model:  10

    delegate: RadioButton {
    }

}
```